# PHP, using timestamp for mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, insert, timestamp

I've been trying to search for a straight answer, but for some reason the answer isn't coming to me. I was wondering what is the best way to store date/time into mysql?

I researched that timestamp in mysql is good because it will update depending on timezones too.

So I've set my column name as `timestamp` with `datatype` in mysql to timestamp, but what is the best syntax for storing current date/time to that?

```
"INSERT INTO table(timestamp) VALUES(now())" //or use timestamp()? or is there such thing?
```

?

Please help, thanks!

Comment: OT: It's always not a good idea to name things using `reserved words`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `datetime` datatype in your table and just store it as `NOW()` which will store it as `YYYY-MM-DD HHHH:MM:SS`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some considerations:

- Set the column type to `BIGINT` so you can store 64-bit timestamps
- You can insert using the PHP [`time()`](http://php.net/time) function, or MySQL's [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function
- Name your column something other than `timestamp`.  It is a permitted word<sup>[1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) see last section</sup>, but its also a type in MySQL.

If you store times as a Unix timestamp in MySQL, they are stored in UTC which makes dealing with timezone conversion very easy.  In a 64-bit environment, PHP can handle dates up to the year 219,250,468.

Both of these queries are the same:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`time`) VALUES(UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
// or
$time = time();
INSERT INTO `table` (`time`) VALUES($time);
```

Then to display it in PHP:

```
SELECT `time` from `table` WHERE `id` = 1;
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s e', $row['time']); // 2012-07-31 23:59:59 America/Los_Angeles
```

Whatever timezone is set in PHP [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set) will be the timezone used when you output the date in PHP.

Comment: my only concern is the timezone. so should i have `date_default_timezone_set()` in all my pages? say if its `'America/Los_Angeles'`, people from UK, they will be seeing los angeles timezone? How would PHP know that time should be UK time zone if I have `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles')` on all pages? Thanks!

Comment: don't do this, it makes the timestamps dependent on your webserver providing consistent times.. which may not scale across multiple webservers properly

Comment: Note that the queries you provided are only the same if your MySQL server and PHP server are set with the same time/timezone.

Comment: For that very reason I'm always using the `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` function of MySQL and process the time gathered from the db later on the clientside.

Comment: No matter what timezone you are in, a Unix timestamp will be UTC, and they will be displayed to whatever timezone PHP is set to use.  You can try to detect the timezone of your user based on IP settings, or have your users select the timezone they want to see; otherwise you can display it in server time or GMT if you want.  But either way, storing timestamps makes it easy to go between timezones and makes dealing with DST easier.